# Did Loker ever start getting paid again?

Tags: character, lie-to-me

Towards the end of season 1 of [Lie To Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1235099/), Dr. Lightmen demoted Loker to an unpaid intern instead of firing him for [divulging sensitive information to the SEC while working on a case](http://lietome.wikia.com/wiki/Eli_Loker). Did Loker ever start getting paid again? If so, at what point did he start getting paid? If not, then how did he afford to stick around continue working for free? Surely he has bills to pay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Season 2 Episode 21 ("Darkness and Light") has Torres and Loker competing for a promotion (to Vice President) which Loker snags.  That should probably mark the end of his unpaid internship.  Though why the writers didn't dwell more on this significant change in later episodes (starting season 3) is up in the air. Probably why if you missed/forgot about this one, you'd think nothing changed for Loker.

Comment: I guess I must have overlooked it.